# Возможно ли создать переменную переменной в js

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли создать переменную переменной объекта в js
Задача такая. У нас есть цикл в котором название дива для innerHTML создаётся используя строку и цифру.
Пишу абсурд и так нельзя, но суть я думаю вы поймёте.

```
<div id="id0"><span class="class1"> Текст' + iii + '</span> </div>
<div id="id1"><span class="class1"> Текст' + iii + '</span> </div>
<div id="id2"><span class="class1"> Текст' + iii + '</span> </div>


<script>
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        varvar = 'id' + i;
        varvar.innerHTML = 'Текст ' + i + ' изменён';   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: в целом можно, в качестве ключа объекта или элеменат массива. но, думаю, у вас проблемаXY

Comment: т.е. вы делаете не то, что надо бы)

Comment: то есть вот так можно будет varvar[i].innerHTML ?

Comment: Попробовал название объекта определить в переменную из массива, так не работает.

Comment: Какую вообще задачу вы решаете таким способом?  Вам просто надо в диве вывести текст `Текст1`,`Текст2`,`Текст3` и т.д.? Или что? Можно поподробнее?

Comment: Объяснять глобально задачу не смогу, очень сильно накручено все. Вопрос задал выше.спасибо, что откликнулись

Comment: Для текущего примера данные переменные уже созданы и достаточно просто получить их из DOM, для этого нужно просто использовать [`.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) а именно заменить строчку `varvar = 'id' + i;` на `varvar = document.getElementById('id' + i);`

Comment: Да, спасибо большое! Помогло решить проблему. :)

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу никакого смысла как-то заводить переменные переменных, если задача вывести в каждый из элементов текст и номер п/п. Для этого достаточно цикла по элементам, которые можно едино идентифицировать.

```js
let testDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

testDivs.forEach((div, i) => {
    div.querySelector('.class1').innerHTML = `Текст ${i}`;
});
```

```css
.test {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><span class="class1"></span></div>
<div class="test"><span class="class1"></span></div>
<div class="test"><span class="class1"></span></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за пример!